# Redux state wont propagate to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I've been attempting to make a component using Reacts component functionality. In this case I was particularly interested in componentDidMount.

However, no matter what I try, my state wont propagate to the component.

Here is the component:

```
class MainPage extends React.Component
{
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.actions.requestPosts();
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="main-page">
                <PreviewList posts={this.props.posts}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    posts: state.main_posts,
    errors: state.main_errors
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        actions: {
            requestPosts: () => dispatch(requestPosts())
        }
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage);
```

The reducer:

```
export default (state = {main_posts: [], main_errors: []}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case USER_REQUESTS_POSTS_SUCCEEDED:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                main_posts: action.posts
            });
        case USER_REQUESTS_POSTS_FAILED:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                main_errors: action.errors
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

For the purpose of simplicity, I did not include the import statements. I use redux-thunk. I've tested the actions, they successfully arrive at the reducer. The new state is successfully created and returned. It simply does not arrive at the desired component however.

I have tried researching and I've only found examples of reducers that mutated the state, but I can't see anything where I mutate the state. What am I doing wrong? (Ironically the code is similiar to my other react apps that work fine).

In case it is helpful, here is my store:

```
export const history = createHistory();

const middleware = [
    thunk,
    routerMiddleware(history)
];

const reducers = {
    main: mainReducer,
    router: routerReducer
};

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers(reducers),
    {},
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)  
);

export default store;
```

EDIT: As requested, here are my actions:

```
export const USER_REQUESTS_POSTS_SUCCEEDED = 'user/REQUESTS/POSTS/SUCCESS';
export const USER_REQUESTS_POSTS_FAILED = 'user/REQUESTS/POSTS/FAILURE';

export const requestPosts = () => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return fetchPosts().then(
            posts => dispatch(requestPostsSucceeded(posts)),
            errors => dispatch(requestPostsFailed(errors))
        );
    };
};

function fetchPosts() {
    return Promise.resolve([{title: 'Test Post', content_short: 'Hello World', author: 'Extremo', category: 'development', tags: ['test'], date: '15.11.17'}]);
}

export const requestPostsSucceeded = (posts) => {
    return {type: USER_REQUESTS_POSTS_SUCCEEDED, posts: posts};
};

export const requestPostsFailed = (errors) => {
    return {type: USER_REQUESTS_POSTS_FAILED, errors: errors};
};
```

Comment: Can you show us `requestPosts`?

Comment: @nem035 I've updated my question. Remember however that the reducer does receive the posts and does generate the new state with the posts.

Comment: Are you using the [`<Provider>`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store) then?

Comment: @nem035 I am using Provider with the store passed as argument, inside I also use the ConnectedRouter with the history since I use react-router and inside that the App with the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From store definition

```
const reducers = {
    main: mainReducer,
    router: routerReducer
};
```

You should access your component state using your `component reducer's key`

which is `main`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    posts: state.main.main_posts,
    errors: state.main.main_errors
});
```

Comment: It is intentionally that I do not use the previous posts. I will edit my question in a moment to show what exactly requestPosts is doing! One minute.

Comment: There, I updated my answer and added the actions. The action is being called, the reducer receives the action information and generates the new state.. it just doesn't arrive at the component.

Comment: @Extremo thanks for info.Please check updated answer

Comment: Thank you! This was it. I can't believe the solution was right infront of my eyes but I was blind to it. Typical.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mapStateToProps` function should be:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    posts: state.main.main_posts,
    errors: state.main.main_errors
  }
}
```

You are passing down posts and errors as `undefined` currently

Comment: Thanks for the tip that the check is unnecessary but it still doesn't fix the problem with the state/props not updating and it not being re-rendered

Comment: Oh I just realized you mentioned that it never gets dispatched, when it actually does. Interesting though that it shouldn't have! Because I tested it and the action was always called and the posts generated. Hmm

Comment: Ah I see the issue now, you just need to fix your `mapStateToProps` hook, I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I am so glad we've got it figured out. I couldn't see the error myself :)